# Зачем нужны Nothing, Null, Nil и None

Tags: scala

Судя по именам все типы означают одно и тоже.
В каких случаях в `scala` нужно применять: `Nothing`, `Null`, `Nil` и `None`, чем они отличаются?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Хорошо расписано [тут](http://programador.ru/scala-and-nothing/). Кое-что добавлю, кое-что подрезюмирую.

Тип **Nothing** - это самый нижний тип. Это значит что переменные с таким типом можно присвоить к абсолютно любому другому типу.

Пример 1:

```
def isTen(number: Int): Boolean =
  if (10 == number) true
  else throw new Exception("Number is not ten")
```

`true` имеет тип `Boolean`, кидание исключения имеет тип `Nothing` и так как `Nothing` в иерархии типов наследник `Boolean`, то в результате получается тип `Boolean`.

Пример 2:

```
def genericIsTen[T](value: T): T =
  if (10 == value) value
  else throw new Exception("Generic is not ten")
```

Так как `Nothing` **самый** нижний тип, значит в иерархии типов наследник **любого** типа - вместо `Boolean` может быть и дженерик.

Пример 3:

```
trait Box[+T]

case class Full[T](value: T) extends Box[T]
object Empty extends Box[Nothing]

def boxedIsTen(value: Int): Box[Int] =
  if (10 == value) Full(value)
  else Empty
```

Аналогично примерам выше объект с типом `Box[Nothing]` спокойно присваивается к типу `Box[Int]` (благодаря *ковариантности*, т.е. тому плюсику у трейта).

Вывод, как видишь тип `Nothing` используется тогда, когда нужно чтоб тип был принят другим типом. "Перетёрт" другим типом.

---

Тип **Null** - это **почти** самый нижний тип. В иерархии типов - он наследник всех объектов, но не наследник всех примитивов. А значит он будет работать для объектов точно также как и Nothing.

```
isTen(null) // НЕ будет работать так как функция хочет примитив
genericIsTen((null) // будет работать
boxedIsTen(null) // НЕ будет работать так как функция хочет Int
```

---

**Nil** - это не тип, это объект `Nil`. Тип у этого объекта `Nil.type`. Объект `Nil` - один из двух наследников класса `List` и используется он там, где нужен пустой список типа `List`. Ну и так как он наследник `List`-а, у него доступны все его методы.

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] { /* ... */ }

case object Nil extends List[Nothing] { /* ... */ }
final case class ::[B]( /* ... */ ) extends List[B] { /* ... */}

def listIsTen(number: Int): List[Int] =
  if (10 == number) List(number)
  else Nil
```

---

**None** - это тоже не тип, а объект `None`. Тип у этого объекта `None.type`. Объект `None` - один из двух наследников класса `Option` и используется как пустой вариант `Option`.

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A]

case object None extends Option[Nothing] { /* ... */ }
final case class Some[+A](x: A) extends Option[A] { /* ... */ }

def optionIsTen(number: Int): Option[Int] =
  if (10 == number) Some(number)
  else None
```

Comment: `Тип Nothing - это самый нижний тип` — то есть он наследуется ото всех и сразу множественным наследованием? Но тогда он должен реализовывать и методы всех объектов. А если это не так, то это не ООП-ное наследование, а просто специальное значение.

Comment: @Arhad, иерархия типов идет отдельно от иерархии классов. Типы не имеют методов, поэтому и ничего не наследуется.

Comment: @Arhad: Можно условно считать, что он реализует все возможные методы (всё равно вызвать их невозможно). Точно так же как вы можете считать, что объект, возвращаемый куском кода `() => throw new Exception()` на C#, реализует все возможные методы.